# azure open ai embeddings qna with subset of files uploaded

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, openai-api, azure-openai, openaiembeddings

I am new to Azure OpenAI and below is what I am trying to achieve.

I want to use Azure OpenAI services for qna on a pdf file.
I have gone through few documents and blogs related to this and this is what I have understood so far. I can upload my files to Azure blob storage and create embeddings which will then reside on a vector database like Redis. These embeddings will be finally used for search/qna.

So far this is all good. now lets say I have uploaded some 100 documents and created embeddings for the same. now if I do a search it will look out in all the embeddings for these 100 documents, but I want to a search/qna only for a single document.

Is is possible to do this search on specific document or subset of the documents/embeddings? if so , how ?

Thanks.

References :

https://github.com/ruoccofabrizio/azure-open-ai-embeddings-qna

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo

Comment: Can you provide some more details such code, error log, and documentation you followed? This can help in finding the solution.
Meanwhile, you can try storing the embeddings with some document identifier for each document and load embedding based to search based on query and your document ID to search over specific document.

Comment: Hi @RishabhM , i have updated my question with references.